# Using the file name captured with the html browse button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a form where I can upload demographic information such as name, etc. as well as upload jpg image files. I cannot figure out how to catch the file the user chooses from the browse button.  Where is the file name stored?  How can I access it for the upload? How can I access it to assign it as a variable eg:

```
var theFileName; 
function() 
if (filename !=null) { //manipulate the variable }; 
else { //something else};
```

I am new to JavaScript and trying to teach myself with web sources and books and cannot seem to find an answer. In addition to an answer to this question, can anyone suggest a good web source for further information on this subject? The ultimate goal is to be able to upload the info and files with PHP into a database so it can be recalled on another page but a different user.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('id_of_element').files[0].name`

Comment: Be aware that the file object is deemed a security risk so your access may be restricted from browser to browser and is for example not even available in mobile safari

Comment: thank you.  I am assuming I need to add an id to the button HTML.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EDfsh/

if you look into this fiddle i've made, you have the code you need ;)

It uses jQuery.

Your HTML Input

```
<input type="file" id="pic" >
```

JavaSCript:

```
function fileName(test){
    var source=test.value;
    alert(source);
}

$(function(){
    $('#pic').bind('change',function(){
        fileName(this);
    });
});
```

But you cannot see the source of the file. And you don't have the rights to see the whole path. So you just get the file name.